# Solving : $y'' + 4x = \sec2x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I got this question in an exam. I have tried a lot to solve it but have not been able to as the second integration of $\sec 2x$ becomes impossible.

$$y'' +  4x = \sec2x$$

Comment: Doesn't have a solution in terms of standard functions. Are you sure you were asked this particular ODE or is there a typo ?

Comment: Might have been a typo in the exam but not here.

Comment: Do you actually mean $4x$ and not $4y$?

Comment: Typo in the exam is almost impossible but could be a weird case. The solution of this ODE is a very,very long expression involving the polylogarithm function $\text{Li}(x)$. Are you familiar with such a thing ?

Comment: If it were $$y’’ + 4y = \sec(2x)$$ instead, that would be a pretty problem :-p

Comment: I am not familiar with polylog. It was undergraduate calculus. Would have been a typo.

Comment: How would you solve it if the question had 4y in place 4x?